# Javascript, for each unique value in key

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array containing many objects with key value pairs.

The objects could look something like this:

```
var item = {
    'product_type' : product_type,
    'product_id' : product_id,
    'product_name' : product_name,
};
```

I want to loop through the array holding these objects, and for each unique product_type I want to do something, say output some wrapper markup for that product type. How can I do this?

The values in product_type could be: meat, icecream and vegetables for example. So I want to output a wrapping div for meat, one for icecream and one for vegetables, but only one for each type so even if there are two meat products there are not two meat wrappers.

Comment: Iterate over the array and use the product_type as a key in a new object. Duplicate keys would just overwrite the old ones, and you'd end up with an object with unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for a simple `for()` loop.

For your example you could do something like this:

```
var item = {
    'product_type' : product_type,
    'product_id' : product_id,
    'product_name' : product_name,
};
for(var key in item ){ //each key in your object
   if(key === 'product_type' && item[key] === 'icecream'){
   //The value of the product_type is icecream!
   }
}
```

edit:

if you have an array of objects like this: `[{key:'value'}]`, you could loop through the array and if you know for which key you are looking for you can access its value like this:

```
for(var key in array){ //each key in your array
   if(array[key]['product_type'] === 'icecream'){
   //The value of the product_type is icecream!
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I'm unsure...my objects doesn't have names, they just have an index in the array which holds them. How do I proceed then?

Comment: @JohanDahl its exactly the same, you will find the index in the key variable

Comment: But wont this loop output my wrapper for each time a product_type === icecream?

I only want to output one wrapper for icecream, even if there 4 objects with the product type icecream in the array.

Comment: then stop the loop or count the product types?